# campo data com order by direto no mysql exibe um resultado e no php sai diferente

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou tentando exibir uma consulta ordenada pelo **mês** de um campo **data**, no `phpmyadmin` a consulta sai certinha e quando exibo o resultado da mesma consulta com php a data sai da ordem correta.

consulta:

```
"select calendario.id_calendario, calendario.id_download, eventos.id_evento, eventos.descricao, str_to_date(concat(dia, '/', mes, '/', ano) , '%d/%m/%Y') as data
from calendario 
inner join eventos on calendario.id_evento = eventos.id_evento
order by month(data) asc , eventos.descricao asc"
```

no mysql exibe assim (o correto)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e no php exibe assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A única diferença é que eu formato a data no php para `dd/mm/aaaa` mas isto é depois da consulta, alguém ja passou por isto?

Comment: Não é mais fácil só usar um `date_format()`? não precisa converter um campo date em date.

Comment: São tres campos int (dia, mes e ano) utilizo assim porque tenho uma função de calendário que emite guias de pagamento baseada no campo "dia" que antecipa as datas de pagamento no caso de sabados, domingos e feriados. E também porque o cliente quer entrar apenas com o dia na hora de cadastrar os eventos, mas como tenho que manter os eventos cadastrados por até 60 dias na hora da exibição da listagem dos eventos se eu não colocar a data completa não tem como diferenciar um mesmo evento que ocorreu em janeiro de um que ocorre em fevereiro.

Comment: Você está usando um CONCAT para unir dia, mes e ano, por que não usa ORDER BY calendario.mes, eventos.descricao?? (acredito que os ASC não se fazem necessários)

Comment: Bom dia Thiago, realmente simplifica a consulta desse jeito e o resultado é o mesmo, só que as consultas não estão sendo exibidas através do php com o mesmo resultado que sai no phpmyadmin

Comment: O ideal é que você coloque seu código em PHP também, porque o erro deve estar lá.

Answer (score 2):

Descobri o problema, não tem nada a ver com php ou mysql, estou usando bootstrap com datatables e a API sempre inicializava pela coluna 0
daí desativando os parametros do datatables funcionou. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

```
$('#tabela1').dataTable( {
    order: [],
    columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [0] } ]
});
```